# Using mechanize bing search returns blank page

Tags: python, beautifulsoup, mechanize, bing

I am using mechanize to perform a bing search and then I will process the results with beautiful soup.  I have successfully performed google and yahoo searches with this same method but when I do a bing search all I get is a blank page.

I am thoroughly confused why this is the case and if anyone can shed any light on the matter that would be greatly appreciated.  Here is a sample of the code I'm using:

```
from BeautifulSoup import BeautifulSoup
import mechanize
br = mechanize.Browser()
br.set_handle_robots(False)
br.open("http://www.bing.com/search?count=100&q=cheese")
content = br.response()
content = content.read()
soup = BeautifulSoup(content, convertEntities=BeautifulSoup.ALL_ENTITIES)
print soup
```

The result is a blank line printed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You probably got response that answer is already in your browser cache. Try changing a little you query string, for example decrease count to 50.

You can also add some debugging code and see headers returned by server:

```
br.open("http://www.bing.com/search?count=50&q=cheese")
response = br.response()
headers = response.info()
print headers
content = response.read()
```

*EDIT:*

I have tried this query with `count=100` with Firefox and Opera browsers and it seems that bing do not like such a "big" count. When I decrease count then it works. So this is not mechanize or other Python library fault, but your query is problematic to bing. It also seems that browser can query bing with `count=100` but it must first query bing with some smaller count. Strange!

Comment: Thanks for your insight.  I repeated the search changing the count to 50 and it worked as expected, numerous times.  I changed count back to 100 and it didn't work again... Seems strange.

Also I did the debug you suggested here is the output for count=100

    Cache-Control: no-cache
    Content-Length: 0
    Date: Fri, 19 Nov 2010 12:42:00 GMT
    Connection: close
    Set-Cookie: OVR=flt=0&flt2=0&flt3=0&flt4=0&flt5=0&ramp1=0&release=or3&preallocation=0&R=1; domain=.bing.com; path=/

Comment: I edited answer: this query do not work from regular browsers! At least for the first time. Really strange,

Answer (score 0):

Another way to achieve this is by using `requests` with `beautifulsoup`

Code and example in [online IDE](https://replit.com/@DimitryZub1/Scrape-Bing-Search-Python-SerpApi#bs4_results/get_organic.py):

```py
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests, lxml, json

headers = {
    'User-agent':
    "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/70.0.3538.102 Safari/537.36 Edge/18.19582"
}


def get_organic_results():
  html = requests.get('https://www.bing.com/search?q=nfs', headers=headers)
  soup = BeautifulSoup(html.text, 'lxml')

  bing_data = []

  for result in soup.find_all('li', class_='b_algo'):
    title = result.h2.text
    try:
      link = result.h2.a['href']
    except:
      link = None
    displayed_link = result.find('div', class_='b_attribution').text
    try:
      snippet = result.find('div', class_='b_caption').p.text
    except:
      snippet = None

    for inline in soup.find_all('div', class_='b_factrow'):
      try:
        inline_title = inline.a.text
      except:
        inline_title = None
      try:
        inline_link = inline.a['href']
      except:
        inline_link = None

        bing_data.append({
        'title': title,
        'link': link,
        'displayed_link': displayed_link,
        'snippet': snippet,
        'inline': [{'title': inline_title, 'link': inline_link}]
      })

  print(json.dumps(bing_data, indent = 2))

# part of the created json output:
'''
[
  {
    "title": "Need for Speed Video Games - Official EA Site",
    "link": "https://www.ea.com/games/need-for-speed",
    "displayed_link": "https://www.ea.com/games/need-for-speed",
    "snippet": "Need for Speed Forums Buy Now All Games Forums Buy Now Learn More Buy Now Hit the gas and tear up the roads in this legendary action-driving series. Push your supercar to its limits and leave the competition in your rearview or shake off a full-scale police pursuit \u2013 it\u2019s all just a key-turn away.",
    "inline": [
      {
        "title": null,
        "link": null
      }
    ]
  }
]
'''
```

Alternatively, you can do the same thing using [Bing Organic Results API](https://serpapi.com/bing-organic-results) from SerpApi. It's a paid API with a free trial of 5,000 searches.

Code to integrate:

```py
from serpapi import GoogleSearch
import os

def get_organic_results():
  params = {
    "api_key": os.getenv('API_KEY'),
    "engine": "bing",
    "q": "nfs most wanted"
  }

  search = GoogleSearch(params)
  results = search.get_dict()

  for result in results['organic_results']:
    title = result['title']
    link = result['link']
    displayed_link = result['displayed_link']
    try:
      snippet = result['snippet']
    except:
      snippet = None
    try:
      inline = result['sitelinks']['inline']
    except:
      inline = None
    print(f'{title}\n{link}\n{displayed_link}\n{snippet}\n{inline}\n')

# part of the output:
'''
Need for Speed: Most Wanted - Car Racing Game - Official ...
https://www.ea.com/games/need-for-speed/need-for-speed-most-wanted
https://www.ea.com/games/need-for-speed/need-for-speed-most-wanted
Jun 01, 2017 · To be Most Wanted, you’ll need to outrun the cops, outdrive your friends, and outsmart your rivals. With a relentless police force gunning to take you down, you’ll need to make split-second decisions. Use the open world to …
[{'title': 'Need for Speed No Limits', 'link': 'https://www.ea.com/games/need-for-speed/need-for-speed-no-limits'}, {'title': 'Buy Now', 'link': 'https://www.ea.com/games/need-for-speed/need-for-speed-heat/buy'}, {'title': 'Need for Speed Undercover', 'link': 'https://www.ea.com/games/need-for-speed/need-for-speed-undercover'}, {'title': 'Need for Speed The Run', 'link': 'https://www.ea.com/games/need-for-speed/need-for-speed-the-run'}, {'title': 'News', 'link': 'https://www.ea.com/games/need-for-speed/need-for-speed-payback/news'}]
'''
```

> Disclaimer, I work for SerpApi.